# IE conditional statements do not work with JavaScript disabled?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, comments, conditional-statements

I have a page with IE conditional comments in head section, nothing fancy just:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/IE7.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

It works as expected when JavaScript is on. When JS is off IE doesn't seem to read IE7.css though. I wanted to make my site able to run with or without JS, validate and all and wanted to avoid CSS hacks at all costs hence conditional comments.

Could someone with more experience with conditional comments and JS-off tell me if there is any way at all to get conditional statements work without JS?

Comment: IE's conditional comments do not use or require JavaScript. Whatever effect you're encountering has to be coincidental. Can you provide more detail on what you're doing and how you know it's not reading the conditional comment?

Comment: Dumb question, but do you have IE7 at work? Also, if you have IE7, do you possibly have Google Chrome frame installed?

Answer (score 0):

I was just about to post the code when I realized that I forgot to update links when copied my html templates into framework I created and so the code I pasted above should actually be:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/<?php echo Registry::getVariable("theme") ?>/css/findadsIE7.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Embarassing mistake and now all works just fine. I was too fast to blame microsoft this time ;)

Comment: This question was bumped as the system assumed you hadn't solved it yet. Please mark your answer accepted so it knows it's solved :)